# Empty last line before page breaks using mdframed

Tags: page-breaking, mdframed

When using mdframed, there is an empty last line before page breaks as follows

```
|----------------------------|
| xxxx xxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxx |
| xxxx xxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxx |
|                            |
<page break>
| xxxx xxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxx |
| xxxx xxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxx |
|----------------------------|
```

How to fill this last line of the page? Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=0pt,topline=false,
innertopmargin=2pt,innerbottommargin=2pt,innerleftmargin=2pt,innerrightmargin=2pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{gray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{8mm}|p{4cm}|p{8cm}|p{2.45cm}|}\hline
\rowcolor{gray} \bf No. & \bf Title & \bf WP Leader & \bf Months \\\hline
WP1 & Title & Partner & m6--m45 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace*{-2pt}
\begin{mdframed}
\textbf{Objectives}\quad
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{mdframed}%
\begin{mdframed}
\textbf{Description of Work and Role of Partners}\quad
\lipsum[4-7]
\end{mdframed}%
\begin{mdframed}
\textbf{Description of Deliverables}\quad
\lipsum[4-8]
\end{mdframed}%

\vspace{2pt}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{8mm}|p{4cm}|p{8cm}|p{2.45cm}|}\hline
\rowcolor{gray} \bf No. & \bf Title & \bf WP Leader & \bf Months \\\hline
WP2 & Title & Partner & m6--m45 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace*{-2pt}
\begin{mdframed}
\textbf{Objectives}\quad
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{mdframed}%
\begin{mdframed}
\textbf{Description of Work and Role of Partners}\quad
\lipsum[4-7]
\end{mdframed}%
\begin{mdframed}
\textbf{Description of Deliverables}\quad
\lipsum[4-8]
\end{mdframed}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The extra space below is `splitbottomskip`. The documentation says the default is `0pt`, but that is not true: it is `10pt`. And so is `splittopskip` but I think this is measured from the baseline of the first line to the top of the frame, so that seems reasonable.

So the solution is to add `splitbottomskip=0pt` to `\mdfsetup`.

Answer (score 1):

With `tcolorbox` you can play with `topsep at break` and `bottomsep at break` to adjust these spaces.

Your example adapted to `tcolorbox` could be:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{sharp corners, size=tight, boxsep=2pt, 
colback=white, boxrule=1pt,
before skip=-1pt,
after skip=0pt,
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{gray}{gray}{0.9}

\newtcolorbox{mypar}[2][]{%
enhanced,
breakable,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
coltitle=black,
detach title,
title={#2},
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
bottomsep at break=-1mm,
topsep at break=-1mm,
#1
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx*={\arrayrulewidth1pt}{p{8mm}|p{4cm}|p{8cm}|X},
before upper app={\rowcolor{gray}}]
\textbf{No.} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{WP Leader} & \textbf{Months}\\\hline
WP1 & Title & Partner & m6--m45
\end{tcolorbox}%
\begin{mypar}{Objectives}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{mypar}%
\begin{mypar}{Description of Work and Role of Partners}
\lipsum[4-7]
\end{mypar}%
\begin{mypar}{Description of Deliverables}
\lipsum[4-8]
\end{mypar}%

\vspace{2pt}

\noindent
\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx*={\arrayrulewidth1pt}{p{8mm}|p{4cm}|p{8cm}|X},
before upper app={\rowcolor{gray}}]
\textbf{No.} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{WP Leader} & \textbf{Months}\\\hline
WP1 & Title & Partner & m6--m45
\end{tcolorbox}%
\begin{mypar}{Objectives}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{mypar}%
\begin{mypar}{Description of Work and Role of Partners}
\lipsum[4-7]
\end{mypar}%
\begin{mypar}{Description of Deliverables}
\lipsum[4-8]
\end{mypar}%

\end{document}
```

Intial `tabular` has been declared with a `tcolorbox` with `tabularx*` option and also new `mypar` boxes with a mandatory parameter for box title has been defined. The result looks like:

[image]